# Final Fantasy XV: Any references to FF XIII and FF Type-0?

Tags: final-fantasy-15, final-fantasy-13, final-fantasy-type-0-hd

So, I'm about to start playing Final Fantasy XV. By reading a bit about it on the internet, I figured out, that FFXV is a part of the "Fabula Nova Crystallis FF" subseries, which also includes FFXIII and FF Type-0.
Reading further, I even got the information, that FFXV was originally labeled "FFXIII Versus" before it became to big and turned into a major FF.
But I haven't found out anything over than the simple fact, that all of these titles share the same mythos.

So here's my question:

Is there anything important in FFXV, that refers to FFXIII or Type-0, which I won't understand to it's fullest unless I play these titles beforehand?
For example, does FFXV require a basic grip of said mythos or do I get all the information I need in FFXV?

And yes, I don't know anything about the mythos itself as of now, as I don't want to spoil myself, if it isn't important.

Comment: i don't think there is unless there are any Fal'cie or l'Cie in XV. i read somewhere that the New World from *Lightning Return* and the setting of *Final Fantasy XIII: Reminiscence -tracer of memories-* was XV's world but haven't been able to validate that

Comment: To add to this. I'd posit that they are all around that sub-series primarily because FF13, FF15 and Type-0 were all originally supposed to be part of the 13 series. FF15 was supposed to be FF13 Versus as a Playstation exclusive.

Answer (score 1):

While they may be apart of the [Fabula Nova Crystallis](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fabula_Nova_Crystallis_Final_Fantasy) sub-series, they are all their own individual games with no reference to one another - except for the XIII trilogy. The reason why they are apart of the sub-series is due to common mythology within the games

> **Fabula Nova Crystallis Final Fantasy** is a series of games within the Final Fantasy video game franchise. It was primarily developed by series creator and developer Square Enix, which also acted as publisher for all titles. While featuring various worlds and different characters, each Fabula Nova Crystallis game is ultimately based on and expands upon a common mythos focusing on important crystals tied to deities. The level of connection to the mythos varies between each title.
>
> ........
>
> **The universes of XIII, Type-0 and XV are unrelated to each other, though common elements and themes are present**